# Tag pages do not show

Tags: permalinks, tags

### problem:

When I request a "tag" page e.g. /tag/whatever no tag page shows up only the frontpage. This also seems to be the case with categories

### what did i do

- I have moved this blog from single site to my WP3 Multisite setup (#21)

### What Did I try already

- The other 20 moved weblogs work OK so it is not "generic" or .htacess or wpconfig
- I have tried other themes like 2010 : the same problem
- Just to be sure I flushed the permalinks
- "if(is_tag()) { echo ""; } else { echo ""; }" always show "no tag"... in other words the page itself does not think it is a tag page
- the table structures and database contents for terms, etc... look ok
- i have a template page "tag.php" with in it "hello tag", this one does not show
- the backend looks completely ok: tags show with posts etc..
- the tags DO appear under the posts
- template_loader-php : the is_tag = false

### Current Hypothesis

- the query parser in query.php shows the correct tag in the array but the new
  $this->parse_tax_query( $qv ); hmmm maybe returns the wrong thing?
- any leads to give a brain spark? must be something stupid

? COULD it be that in query.php in the function parse_tax_query... there is no check for the "tag" in a query string??

**UPDATE**: I found it! (but it took some time): it is the simple tags plugin (http://redmine.beapi.fr/projects/show/simple-tags) conflicts with the new parse_tax_query .... in 3.1 .... phew!

Answer (score 1):

To comply with the QA thread structure:

It was caused by a conflict of simple tags plugin and new code in 3.1 / Trunk Version.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this issue similar to yours. You may take it as reference.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/categories-missing-in-frontend-but-are-in-db?replies=6

Comment: i have no idea why a categories to tags converter would solve my problem but what the heck ... installing...

Comment: unfortunately... nogo. i took one tag that is a category.